# Database vs Resources

Tags: c#, database, resources

I have a project for EDI formats translation, that uses a series of templates.

What would be a better practice:

1. Use a database (we always have the connection open)?
2. Use the project resources to save all of those templates?

Notes:

- The formats change every 6 months.
- But, I have to re-compile every 6 months anyway because I have to adjust for (sometimes big) changes. i.e. the database shouldn't be better just because of "compiling time".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only advantage of using a db, is you could make a change to the content of the templates without changing the code. That would make sense if the db was central, if you deploy it with the application as a local db, then it becomes a very dubious proposition, unless you are already deploying a database anyway.

If you do go for the resources solution. You should consider having a separate dll to hold the resources with a suitable interface and loading it dynamically, (don't forget to check it's your dll, though)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The database run in a external server, (HANA DB) it will be deployed with the application and we initialize it with the customize data.

I would choose the resource option, but I don't understand what do you mean with a separate dll. You mean, put it inside the dll the resource file, and un/load the templates I need in runtime?

Why not directly on the dll who's using it? so I don't have to fight against appdomains and so one.

Comment: Because then you could change the templates by simply re-deploying the dll. Auto-update, customised templates, test the templates without your app, use the templates in an other app. Lots of reasons, doesn't sound from what you've said it's worth it for you though. App domains wouldn't be an issue, dynamic loading isn't hard, not is checking it's signed correctly, but of you don't have a use for the complexity...